# Regex for dollar amount between 3 and 50

Tags: regex

I am close, but I need some help to complete a regex.  Here is the goal:

Should succeed:

- 10.05
- 3.00
- 50

Should fail:

- 55.99 (>50)
- 3.001 (can't have the "1" at the end)
- 0.50  (< 3)
- .99   (< 3)
- $50   (can't have "$")
- 5.2   (if decimal, must have 2 digits after)

Here's the regex I have so far, but it doesn't quite do all the above correctly:

```
^([1-4][0-9]|50|[3-9])+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

Can anyone share the answer?  Thanks!

Comment: Don't use regexes for math. Check the input format with them, but then parse the numbers and check your conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [online utility](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range/42)  that returns a regex for integers when input the lower and upper limits of the range you want. I used it for the part before the `.` with limits 3-50 and after the `.` with limits 0-99. Here is the result:

```
^0*([3-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)(\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Comment: Argh.  This also fails as ones above. Thanks for the help so far ... someone MUST have the answer.  FYI, I use www.radsoftware.com.au (no affiliation).

Comment: We have a winner!  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(50(\.00)?|([1-4][0-9]|[3-9])(\.[0-9][0-9])?)$
```

There were two issues. Firstly, you had allowed non-zero values after the decimal point, even if the value before it was 50. So I separated that out on the top level. Secondly, just remove the `+`. Because due to it, you can have much larger numbers (by chaining `50` and `43` together, for instance).

However, as Bergi mentioned in a comment, it would be better to just check the format, and do the range check separately (without regex). This would be the format check:

```
^\d+(\.\d\d)?$
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the top regex allows some of my failure cases.

Comment: @Mark which ones specifically? Using PHP, all your failure cases fail on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance... just remove the +

^([1-4][0-9]|50|[3-9])(.[0-9][0-9])?$

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `+` before the potential cents. Also, you will need to handle 50$ as a special case, because it can only have `.00` after it and not any cent amount.

Also, I changed the `[0-9]` to the shortcut for digits: `\d`

```
/^((0?[3-9]|[1-4]\d)(\.\d\d)?|50(\.00)?)$/
```

Comment: This also fails some of my cases.

Comment: Really, which ones do you mean? Btw, my regex is equivalent to @m.buettner's one from above

Comment: @Bergi, apparently mine isn't perfect either (although for me it doesn't allow any failure cases)